# How do I determine orientation of vertices in scilab 3dplot?

Tags: plot, 3d, scilab

I want to plot a simple object in scilab (3d). To understand the way scilab works in that regard, I wrote the following example:

```
xx = [[2;2;1;3;],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[2;2;1;1],[1;3;3;1],[3;3;3;3],[3;3;1;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;2;2;3],[1;1;2;2],[3;2;2;3],[3;2;2;1]]

yy = [[2;2;1;1;],[2;2;1;3],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;3;3;1],[3;3;3;3],[3;1;1;3],[1;2;2;1],[1;3;2;2],[1;2;2;3],[3;2;2;3]]

zz = [[0;0;1;1;],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[1;1;2;2],[1;1;2;2],[1;2;2;1],[1;1;2;2],[2;3;3;2],[2;2;3;3],[2;3;3;2],[2;3;3;2]]

col = ones(12,1)*3

plot3d(xx,yy,list(zz,col))
//h = get("hdl")
//h.hiddencolor = -1 // backside and frontside same color
```

with the following result:

While the structure is absolutley fine, the coloring on 2 faces is inside out. I tried to draw the points of the affected faces in different ways counterclockwise/clockwise, different starting points, etc.. But the faces seem to keep oriented inwards the structure. I found a workaround by setting the backside of the faces equal to the frontside (the 2 commented lines in the code) but I want to understand how scilab determines the orientation of the faces for later work. Any clues?

EDIT:

So i tried PTRK's suggestions. While his provided Matrices are definitely different:

[image: scilab output for matrices]

The result is still the same. Even the output of the provided Testscript is different:

[image: scilab plot output]

Perhaps thats some kind of version/system thing? I'm using Scilab 6.0.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a surface defined by 3 nodes: [P1,P2,P3]. Then you must cycle clockwise trough theses nodes to have the right orientation of inside and outside. Here is a drawing explaining it:

[image: Scilab_facet]

3 of your polygones are defined conterclockwise, thoses with  y=1, y=3 and x = 1. When drawing 4 points polygones, to switch the rotation from clockwise to counterclockwise, just swap the 2nd and 4th nodes or 1st and 3rd.

Thus you must set your points as:

```
xx = [[2;2;1;3;],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[2;2;1;1],[1;1;3;3],[3;3;3;3],[3;3;1;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;2;2;3],[1;1;2;2],[3;2;2;3],[3;2;2;1]]

yy = [[2;2;1;1;],[2;2;1;3],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;1;3;3],[3;3;3;3],[3;3;1;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;3;2;2],[1;2;2;3],[3;2;2;3]]

zz = [[0;0;1;1;],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[2;3;3;2],[2;2;3;3],[2;3;3;2],[2;3;3;2]]
```

This will give the desired output :
[image: good_3d_object]

## Scilab 6.0.0 bug

In this version, if your surfaces are parallel to the cartesian axes, then Scilab will direct it along the axis, **no matter how you defined it**. Thus your problem. A workaround could be to offset **one** of the coordinate by a small delta, which must **be not too small**, as shown in below example.

Regarding your problem, if we want to keep the geometry of your object, we could tilt it with a tiny angle: using [rotation matrix](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_de_rotation#Les_matrices_de_base), if the computational cost induced by the rotation of all the coordinates doesn't bother you. Here's your script with the tilted object

```
clc
clear
xdel(winsid())

xx = [[2;2;1;3;],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[2;2;1;1],[1;1;3;3],[3;3;3;3],[3;3;1;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;2;2;3],[1;1;2;2],[3;2;2;3],[3;2;2;1]]

yy = [[2;2;1;1;],[2;2;1;3],[2;2;3;3],[2;2;3;1],[1;1;1;1],[1;1;3;3],[3;3;3;3],[3;3;1;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;3;2;2],[1;2;2;3],[3;2;2;3]]

zz = [[0;0;1;1;],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[0;0;1;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[1;2;2;1],[2;3;3;2],[2;2;3;3],[2;3;3;2],[2;3;3;2]]

col = ones(12,1)*3

figure(1)
set(gcf(),'background',-2)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot3d(xx,yy,list(zz,col))
title('Object with surfaces orthogonal to cartesian axis')
subplot(2,1,2)
// t is angle in radian showing the tilt
t = %pi/10000
c = cos(t)
s = sin(t)
rot = [1,0,0;0,c,-s;0,s,c]*[c,0,s;0,1,0;-s,0,c]*[c,-s,0;s,c,0;0,0,1]
for i=1:size(xx,1)
  for j = 1:size(xx,2)
   xyz=(rot*[xx(i,j);yy(i,j);zz(i,j)])
   x(i,j)=xyz(1)
   y(i,j)=xyz(2)
   z(i,j)=xyz(3)
  end
end
plot3d(x,y,list(z,col))
title('Object with surfaces tildted by an angle of '+string(t)+' rad')
```

### [image: object]

Script showing 2 surfaces defined by the same nodes but in opposite order.

```
clc
clear
xdel(winsid())

figure(1)
set(gcf(),'background',-2)
cr=color('red') // color of the outside surface

P1 = [0,0,0] //
P2 = [0,1,0]
P3 = [1,0,0]

F1 = [P1;P2;P3] // defining surface clockwise
F2 = [P1;P3;P2] //                  counterclockwise

subplot(2,2,1)
plot3d(F1(:,1),F1(:,2),list(F1(:,3),cr*ones(F1(:,3))))
xstring(F1(:,1),F1(:,2),['P1','P2','P3']) 
title('surface is [P1,P2,P3] with z_P3=0')
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[0,1,0,1,-1,1])

subplot(2,2,2)
plot3d(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),list(F2(:,3),cr*ones(F2(:,3))))
xstring(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),['P1','P3','P2'])
title('surface is [P1,P3,P2] with z_P3=0, broken with Scilab 6.0.0')
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[0,1,0,1,-1,1])

subplot(2,2,3)
plot3d(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),list(F2(:,3)+[0;0;10^-7],cr*ones(F2(:,3))))
xstring(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),['P1','P3','P2'])
title('surface is [P1,P3,P2] with |z_P3| < 10^-8')
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[0,1,0,1,-1,1])

subplot(2,2,4)
plot3d(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),list(F2(:,3)+[0;0;10^-8],cr*ones(F2(:,3))))
xstring(F2(:,1),F2(:,2),['P1','P3','P2'])
title('surface is [P1,P3,P2] with |z_P3| = 10^-8, broken in 6.0.0')
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[0,1,0,1,-1,1])
```

### Scilab 5.5.1

[image: Examples]

### Scilab 6.0.0

[image: Examples]

Comment: Hi! Thanks alot for your answer! Please see the edit of my question!

Comment: Thank you very much! Good to know it's kind of a bug afterall. You definitely explained the behaviour and added a workaround, so I'll mark your post as answer. I don't know if this behaviour is intended, we probably should report a bug when scilabs bugtracker is back online.

Comment: At least I wrote on the [scilab mailing list](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Scilab-users-Regression-Fac3d-direct-surfaces-along-cartesian-axis-no-matter-user-definition-td4036962.html)

Comment: @StefanSchallmeiner I've added an idea to your solution if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks again, but i'll stick to my workaround with "h.hiddencolor = -1" to keep the geometry in tact. Usually if the figure represents a volume of some kind, it shouldn't be a problem to make the inside as well as the outside the same color. But as I'm planning to interpret results coming from some kind of finite element simulation I don't want to mess with the geometry.